# loading backbone plugins with requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I was wondering how I could load backbone plugins with require.js I currently have this in my main.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    require.config({
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        deepModel: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'backbone']
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone',
        text: 'lib/requirejs-text/text',
        deepModel: 'lib/deep-model/deep-model.min'
    },
```

In my model I have something like this

```
var myapp = myapp|| {};
(function() {
    'use strict';

    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'deepModel',
    ], function($, _, Backbone) {

        myapp.model= new Backbone.DeepModel.extend({
            defaults: {
            },

            urlRoot: '/users',
```

For some reason the above does not seem to work as expected. I think I am missing something but not sure what that is. I am using [the backbone deep model plugin](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model).

This is the error I get in the debugger

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Comment: You don't need to list libraries in your define statements which are dependencies of other libraries you are listing as dependencies, if the "transitive dependency" exports a variable to the global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add DeepModel to your scope in function signature:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'deepModel',
], function($, _, Backbone, **DeepModel**)
```

Comment: I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'` when I try to make an instance of my model.

Comment: what backbone version you use?

Answer (score 0):

It might make your life easier if you use the AMD-compatible version of backbone and underscore. By default, they do not support AMD.

https://github.com/amdjs/backbone

https://github.com/amdjs/underscore